# Searching a text file for a string in C

Tags: c, string, file, search, text

For part of a program that I am writing, I need to search a text file to see if a certain word exists in the file, and if it does, I want to print it to the screen. Why is using a for loop to string compare such as this:

```
int in_dictionary(char dict[][8], char word[], int size) {
int i;

for (i = 0; i<size; i++)
    if (strcmp(word, dict[i]) == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        return 1;
    }

}
```

Not working for me?

Comment: All your strings are null-terminated? Do you actually store something in them?

Comment: I think you got your return values wrong, 1 is true (`in_dictionary`), 0 is false.

Comment: I put them into the string word when I compare them. Is that not enough for what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 6):

You're only comparing the *first* word in the dictionary to the word you're searching for.  You should only return failure after comparing *all* of the words:

```
for(...) {
    if(dict[i] matches)
        return MATCH;
}
return NO_MATCH;
```

Also, your return values are backwards -- typically, you'd return 0 to indicate failure (no match) and return 1 to indicate success (match).  The exceptions to that are the `main()` function, by convention, and many POSIX system calls (which return 0 for success and -1 for failure).

Comment: I have fixed the return values and I have the if statement returning the word now, but it still seems to not be doing what I want.

Comment: @Eric: Saying that it's not doing what you want is not helpful.  You need to say what it *is* doing **and** what you want.

Comment: it says that the word is not a valid word for the dictionary, but the word is in the text file.

Comment: @Eric: You are still not being helpful.  Show your [code](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#code).  Show your text file.  Show a [short, self-contained, compilable, correct example](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

When `strcmp()` returns a `0` then it means a match was found. At that time you need to return a `1` and not `0`. Also if `strcmp()` returns `1` it means that the current element in the dictionary did not match the search string, at which point you cannot conclude that a match does not exist in the dictionary, it may come later. So only when you've compared the search string with all the elements in the dictionary and not found any match can you conclude that the search string is not in the dictionary.

You need:

```
for (i = 0; i<size; i++) 
    if (strcmp(word, dict[i]) == 0){
        return 1;
    }
return 0;
```